# What happens with continous trap/spell cards when they get negated by Light and Darkness Dragon?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I'm pretty sure they would get destroyed, but people have argued that they stay on the field negated, since the card does not explicitly state "the card gets destroyed and sent to the graveyard."

In my defense I state that it makes no sense that a card never be activated (since LaDD prevents activations) and still remain face up on the field.

They respond that since it never got activated it gets set again, and therefore they think they can get away with activating it every turn to weaken my LaDD.

I'm looking for hard evidence that I can show these kids the next time we have this comes up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These rulings come from [yugioh.wikia.com](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Light_and_Darkness_Dragon), and note:

> These TCG rulings were issued by Upper Deck Entertainment and have since been deemed unofficial by Konami.[18] They were previously considered official and can still be correct, as long as they follow the official gameplay rules, or unless Konami has issued a ruling that says otherwise. References: [19][20][21][22][23][24][25][26]

The relevant rules are:

> “Light and Darkness Dragon” **cannot negate the activation of the Ignition-like effect of Continuous Spell or Trap Cards** (“Ultimate Offering”, etc.) or Field Spell Cards (“Ancient City - Rainbow Ruins”, etc.). “Light and Darkness Dragon's” second effect activates when a Spell or Trap Card is first activated (placed face-up onto the field or flipped face-up).[17](http://web.archive.org/web/20090226121422/http://entertainment.upperdeck.com/yugioh/en/gameplay/faqs/cardfaqs/default.aspx?first=L&last=O)
>
> When “Light and Darkness Dragon” **negates the activation of a Continuous Spell or Trap Card, the Continuous Spell or Trap Card is sent to the Graveyard.** When “Light and Darkness Dragon” negates the activation of “Swords of Revealing Light”, the “Swords of Revealing Light” is sent to the Graveyard.[17](http://web.archive.org/web/20090226121422/http://entertainment.upperdeck.com/yugioh/en/gameplay/faqs/cardfaqs/default.aspx?first=L&last=O)